# Using a Case statement field to populate a parameter

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

Forgive me if I butcher this but I'm fairly new to this: I used a case statement to give additional values to an field, for example

```
CASE Field A > 60 THEN '>60' END AS 'NEW_FIELD'
```

After the WHERE Clause I would like to use this new field as a parameter so 
`AND NEW_FIELD AS (@PARAMETER)`, but Report Builder says it cannot use a column name as a parameter, although I have seen this used in different parameters and works fine. Any advice?

Comment: So update to my original question, if I assign this new field to a parameter and 'NEW FIELD' IN @PARAMETER, no values show when I run the report. I'm assuming because their is no 'NEW FIELD' in the original table, so it Report Builder doesn't find a match and no records are generated?

Answer (score 0):

```
 CASE WHEN Field A > 60 THEN '>60' END =@PARAMETER
```

You can try this in your `WHERE` Clause

Comment: Thanks but still get Invalid Column Name. I've tried with and without the table abbreviation as well and no luck.

Comment: Can you send what u tried exactly and what u need? - @white_homme

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was trying to pass a new CASE field as a parameter. Which was generating an error stating invalid column name. To resolve, I used this CASE field in my report builder table as a field, but in order to pass as a parameter, I essentially used CASE in my WHERE clause like Thiyagu stated above, but had to modify the syntax to - END IN (@Parameter). Thanks!